# How to validate a 5 characters input of textbox that the first 3 characters to letters only and the last 2 characters to numbers c#

Tags: c#

I need to create a method that checks a textbox 5 character inputs. The first 3 characters should be letters and the last 2 characters should be numbers.

here's my current code:

```
public void checkInput(String s) {
   if (CheckInputString(s)) {
//To Check if the first 3 characters are letters and check last 2 characters if numbers
}
   else {
//Invalid
}
```

please help.

Comment: Welcome. Can you show use what you've already tried so far?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: why not use a simple regex like `[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx
[A-Za-z]{3} - Matches 3 alpha
[0-9]{2} - Matches 2 numbers

Test your inputs with given regex online https://regex101.com/r/fF4zG9/5

```
                Regex temp = new Regex("^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{2}$");
                string yourVal = "asd12";
                if(temp.IsMatch(yourVal))
                {
                    //Matches
                }
                else
                {
                    //Fails
                }
```

Comment: Shorter syntax: `if (youVal != null && Regex.IsMatch(youVal, "^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{2}$")) {...} else {...}`. Note `null` as a special case

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to check the string.

```regex
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$
```

Your code could look like this:

```cs
public bool CheckInputString(string s)
{
    System.Text.Regex regex = new System.Text.Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$");
    return regex.IsMatch(s);
}
```

Comment: Please, add *anchors*, e.g. `^` and `$`: your current implementation matches `"bla-bla-bla-ABC12-bla-bla-bla"` input

Comment: Oh right, I've updated the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to simply validate each requirement on the string and then return `true` if they all pass.

```
public static bool IsValid(string input)
{
    return input != null &&                      // Not null
           input.Length == 5 &&                  // Is 5 characters
           input.Take(3).All(char.IsLetter) &&   // First three are letters
           input.Skip(3).All(char.IsDigit);      // The rest are numbers
}
```